# <Error>: ImageIO: PNG invalid PNG file: extra chunks between iDOT and IDAT

Tags: ios, xcode

Just got this funny looking error in my swift project debugger.

There is probably an invalid name of an image somewhere, but I am not sure what `extra chunks between iDOT and IDAT` mean.

Do you have any idea what causes it?

Comment: when i think of invalid png, i had also an issue with it. The problem was, that i renamed a jpeg to png instead of converting it.... well stupid :D could that also happen to you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue is completely random and happened to me too with a few images. Probably another Xcode bug.

1. My image is called "back2@2x.png"
2. I renamed it to "back2.png"
3. Ran the project (the image will appear stretched)
4. Changed it back to "back2@2x.png"
5. Ran project
6. FIXED?!

Good-luck hope it helps!

Comment: Don't really remember what fixed the error. I think I just played around with image files or names like you did.

Answer (score 22):

**Product > Clean Build Folder (with pressed Option)** fixed it for me

Keyboard shortcut - Shift+Option+Command+K

Answer (score 6):

In XCode 8, I cleaned the project (Product->Clean). Then quit XCode. Open it again. Then it works. I haven't changed name of the image. I guess it is just because XCode has some problem. Nothing is wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I just delete all images which have problem to appear and after load again the same images and work perfectly.