# error when loading png image

Tags: ios, xcode, png

The following error appears in the Xcode console when I programmatically load some png images from my bundle in my iOS app.

> read_user_chunkIDOT:1193: invalid PNG file: no valid iEnd chunk

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

My error seems slightly different from the one reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052270/error-imageio-png-invalid-png-file-extra-chunks-between-idot-and-idat). The suggestions and answers in that post did not help me. I have also tried resaving the image in Preview but it did not work.

Edit: The pngs were originally exported with the Sketch mac app as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening and saving the png image as a png image with the Paintbrush mac app without changing anything solved the problem.